# Why simply use PHP variables for dynamic stylesheets?

Tags: php, css, sass, less

I've been reading about dynamic stylesheets and have stumbled across several options, including sass, and less. But my question is why not just turn my `stylesheet.css` into `stylesheet.css.php` and simply use php variables. Then, I avoid all the dependency issues associated with all these other approaches.

Am I overlooking some serious problems by doing it this way?

Comment: Then you'll have extra overload on your server.

Comment: Where as if I used "less" on the client side, the server wouldn't have to work has hard?

Comment: If you mean using `less.js`, server only send the static file to the client-side as the other static files.

Comment: Sass and LESS do a **lot** more than simply variables. Nested CSS rules are something I can't do without these days, and they'd be a pain to implement in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the argument of code re-use: when writing PHP code to generate CSS, you're effectively duplicating (some) of the logic behind things such as sass and less. Why would you do that when there's a widely-used, tested and complete alternative available?

Another thing is performance. Standard CSS files are served by your web server with sane headers regarding caching by the browser. Your browser will not download that same CSS file each time, it just gets it from the browser-side buffer. By default, PHP is not cached at all (and you usually wouldn't want it to be). This means that, by default, your PHP-generated CSS would not be cached, incurring extra load on your server and extra waiting time for your client. While some of this can be solved (including sane header output in the PHP code that generates your CSS), some of it cannot (the overhead of the web server starting up PHP, for example).

Comment: http://verekia.com/slides/css-preprocessors I found this which might be of interest to people as well. And this: http://verekia.com/less-css/dont-read-less-css-tutorial-highly-addictive

Answer (score 2):

> Am I overlooking some serious problems by doing it this way?

I host all static assets on a CDN, which you should too. CDNs don't do PHP.

Also: caching, runtime performance, minification

Comment: Agreed, you beat me to the minification part!! grr

Comment: I dont think this is what OP asked.

Comment: CDN doesn't prevent from using LESS, SASS, minification, or any other dynamic parsing. What should be done is to cache the output of the parsing into a static file, which can be used in any CDN. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP variables used in inline CSS code

Using PHP variables in CSS has many advantages, one of them is that you don't have to learn a new syntax. The use of PHP variables in CSS code is a known practice already implemented in many frameworks, themes, and other website-related scripts.

The most common use is in **inline CSS**. Here is an example of inline CSS making use of PHP variables:

```
<html>
<head>

    <style>
    .class {
        color: <?php echo $text_color; ?>
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This technique is usually used when the PHP variable represents a user setting set via an admin interface. One practical example would be in a WordPress Theme where the user can set the background or text color via the theme's backend.

## PHP variables in an external CSS file

When it comes to external CSS files, it is also possible to use PHP variables, but in order to avoid PHP from parsing your CSS file each time it is retrieved, you would have to save the output to a static file like `stylesheet-processed.css`.

Both SASS and LESS need to be parsed before being saved to a "`.css`" file. The same goes for your PHP file, which you would execute and save the output to a static "`.css`" file, just like the other syntax.

Parsing CSS files is a very common practice and is widely used on many websites, and most well known websites. It is usually done to [increase site's performance](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx) by minifying (~25% saving) the CSS code, combine multiples files into one (less HTTP requests), and gzip (~80% saving) the resulting files.

Here is an example of how you would use PHP variables in a file named `stylesheet.php`, and save the result to `stylesheet.css`:

```
<?php

// Get the parsed CSS code with the 
$processed_CSS = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/stylesheet.php')

// Save the processed CSS to a static CSS file
file_put_contents('stylesheet.css', $processed_CSS);
```

Put the above PHP code into a file named "`parse-css.php`" and access it through your web browser in order to create or update the resulting static CSS file.

And then in your HTML code you would include `stylesheet.css` instead of `stylesheet.php`.

You could improve your *parser* to make it minify the CSS code too, for example using the [CSSMin](https://code.google.com/p/cssmin/) PHP class.